# Parameter not being passed to Controller's action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, parameter-passing

I have two actions in a controller and yet the parameters are not being passed into one of them.

This one: /RouteStop/List/1

And this one: /RouteStop/Details/100

And my global.asax:

`routes.MapRoute(
    "List",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "RouteStop", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );`

routes.MapRoute(
    "Details",
    "{controller}/{action}/{routeID}",
    new { controller = "RouteStop", action = "Details", routeID = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

And here's the actions from my Controller:

`public ActionResult List(string id)
{
  return View();
}`

public ActionResult Details(string routeID)
{
  return View();
}

When I access this URL (/RouteStop/Details/100) the parameter gets passed just fine. But when I access the other one (/RouteStop/List/1) the parameter is null. The names match up as they should but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `{controller}` with List and Details in respective routes. but for your scenario the default routing that you get when you create an MVC app should work.

Comment: So the List route should look like "List/{action}/{id}"?

Comment: @Gary: Correct. The problem with your current routes is that only the first one in your code will be matched as they have the exact same patterns (even if you named on of the parameters different.)